# How do I download an S3 file only if it has changed?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I have a 900 MB file that I'd like to download to disk from S3 if it isn't already in place downloaded. Is there an easy way for me to only download the file if it isn't already in place? I know S3 supports querying MD5 checksum of files, but I'm hoping not to have to build this logic myself.

Answer (score 7):

You can use AWS CLI's [`s3 sync` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html).

> Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. Recursively **copies new and updated files** from the source directory to the destination.

According to [this forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151139), you can use `sync` to synchronize only one file:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/path/ local/path/ --exclude "*" --include "File.txt"
```

It says: sync the given paths, exclude all files, but include `"File.txt"` - so it will sync only `"File.txt"` under those given paths.

---

**Or with the Java SDK:**

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html), there is a [`getObjectMetadata` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObjectMetadata-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which will return information about an S3 object (file) without downloading it's contents.

The method returns an `ObjectMetadata` object which can give you some useful information:

- [`getLastModified` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#getLastModified--):

> Gets the value of the Last-Modified header, indicating the **date and time** at which Amazon S3 **last recorded a modification** to the associated object.

- [`getContentMD5` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#getContentMD5--):

> Gets the **base64 encoded 128-bit MD5 digest** of the associated object (content - not including headers) according to RFC 1864.

- [`getETag` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#getETag--):

> Gets the **hex encoded 128-bit MD5 digest** of the associated object according to RFC 1864.

Comment: This seems to need the ListObjects permission on the source bucket, if I'm not mistaking? That's not always an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I have used below code to download S3 files which have timestamp greater than the local folder timestamp. First it's check if any of the files in S3 folder have timestamp greater than the local folder timestamp. If yes then download those files only.

```
    TransferManager transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().build();
    AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
            Path location = Paths.get("/data/test/");
            FileTime lastModifiedTime = null;
            try {
                lastModifiedTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(location, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Date lastUpdatedTime = new Date(lastModifiedTime.toMillis());        

    ObjectListing listing = amazonS3.listObjects("bucket", "test-folder");
            List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();
            for (S3ObjectSummary os: summaries) {
                if(os.getLastModified().after(lastUpdatedTime)) {
                    try {
                        String fileName="/data/test/"+os.getKey();
                        Download multipleFileDownload = transferManager.download(bucket, os.getKey(), new File(fileName));                        
                        while (multipleFileDownload.isDone() == false) {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }
                    }catch(InterruptedException i){
                        LOG.error("Exception Occurred while downloading the file ",i);
                    }
                }
            }
```